# instance run with the SYSTEM-Accont

Tags: sql-server-2012

i am fairly new to dataware housing, i am trying to attach a database, that i have dowloaded to my dowloads folder and the sql server cannot browse to the location.

i browsed and found this as the closest answer:
https://superuser.com/questions/148668/try-to-attach-to-a-database-file-but-cant-browse-folder-which-contains-the-file

but i dont know how to make my instance run with the SYSTEM-Accont.

please i would appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

The steps required are mentioned below:

1. In SQL Server Configuration Manager, go to SQL Server Services
2. On details panel, right click the name of instance(SQL server) for which you wish  to change the service
3. Next, click on properties.
4. Then login using built in account and chose local system. You will be able to fetch the database.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks , I have been able to solve it, I used this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345578(v=sql.110).aspx

In SQL Server Configuration Manager, click SQL Server Services.
In the details pane, right-click the name of the SQL Server instance for which you want to change the service startup account, and then click Properties.

then i logged on using built in account, and chose local system